# How to find the inverse of the function $(1/4)x^3+x-1$

Tags: calculus, inverse

I am hoping someone can help me find the inverse of the function $(1/4)x^3+x-1$. I first switched $x$ and $y$ in the equation to get $x=(1/4)y^3+y-1$. However, after this stage I was completely stuck trying to solve for $y$, as each time there was always two $y$’s on one side.
Also the question is asking me to find $g^{-1}(x)$ when $x=3$, which I know after I find the inverse I have to substitute $3$ into the equation to get the value. Thanks for any insight!

Comment: please use latex in your question

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to find $g^{-1}(3)$ note that
$$\frac{1}{4}x^3+x-1=3$$
$$\implies x^3+4x-16=0$$
and a solution to this is $x=2$

Comment: Thank you! I see from here I can just interchange x and y now, solve for y, and then input x=3 to get my answer

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark if you think this helped.

Comment: If I were to find the derivative of the inverse when x=3, would I find the derivative of y^3 +4y-16 or would I first derive the original function of (1/4)x^3 +x-1, and then switch the variables, solve for y and then input x=3 to get the y-value?

Comment: you have to first find the inverse and evaluate its derivative at 3

Comment: What I did was used to original inverse function of x=(1/4)y^3+y-1 and I got the derivative y'= x/((3/4)y^2+1) but now I am stuck with too many variable to sub x =3. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Apply [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano%27s_formula) to $x^3 + 4x - (4 + 4y) = 0$.